# How to use Distributed::Process framework in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to use [`Distributed::Process`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Distributed%3a%3aProcess) framework in Perl. I have successfully implemented it in my machine. But I can not make out how to run/test an example script using it. I tried to run the code listing in the [`#synopsis`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Distributed%3a%3aProcess#SYNOPSIS)

Can any one help me out by providing an example script along with the step by step process to test it.

I want to print 'Hello World' in a file in all the worker machine....I modified 3 .pl files available in the above link which are listed below.

`my_worker.pl`:

```
package MyWorker;
use Distributed::Process;
use Distributed::Process::Worker;

sub run {
    my $self = shift;

    # do interesting stuff
   open (MYFILE, '>>data.txt');
   print MYFILE "Hello World\n";
   close (MYFILE);

    # report about what happened
    $self->result("logs the results");
}
```

`my_server.pl`:

```
# Server
use Distributed::Process;
use Distributed::Process::Server;
use Distributed::Process::Master;
use MyWorker;

$master = new Distributed::Process::Master
    -in_handle => STDIN, -out_handle => STDOUT,
    -worker_class => 'MyWorker',
    -n_workers => 2;
$server = new Distributed::Process::Server -port => 8147, -master => $master;

$server->listen();
```

`my_client.pl`:

```
# Client
use Distributed::Process;
use Distributed::Process::Client;
use MyWorker;

$client = new Distributed::Process::Client -worker_class => 'MyWorker',
    -host => localhost, -port => 8147;
$client->run();
```

Then tried to run it using `perl my_worker/server/client.pl` (in different terminal). my_server and client is throwing error as follows:

```
Can't locate MyWorker.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at my_server.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at my_server.pl line 5.
```

I don't know how/where to specify the hostnames or what is the correct process for running it

Comment: Hi Gab.... Thanks for your quick response. I have edited the question with more details... Again, For your information, I have successfully (without any error) installed the tool Distributed::Process running the commands mentioned in its README which are as follows: 
    perl Makefile.PL;
    make;
    make test;
    make install;
please let me know if you need any other info

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because your [`use MyWorker;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) statement cannot find the [`package`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) file.

Basically, you need to rename the file `my_worker.pl` to be `MyWorker.pm`.

Also, you should include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY perl script.  This does not directly touch on your issue, but it will come up if you don't start doing it now.